# LogFactory and Error Logging to Database/Text File

Tags: java, error-logging

Does the below snippet have potential to do error logging to a database or text file?  I know it can write to the Eclipse console.  I'm a .NET developer so I'm not totally sure.

```
private final static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ActivityServiceImpl.class);
```

Comment: I have used Log4J (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) before and had good experiences with it, just another option to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do here. If you *just* want to log to console, you can of course use System.out.println(...). This is easy, but obviously won't add file and line, timestamps, and allow you to control log levels, etc.

If you are starting something more than a toy project, you'll probably be best off with log4j (as was mentioned in your first comment above).

Configuring it to output to a file and/or a console is trivial and there are a number of connectors that will output to a database as well, if that is what you want. Here is one:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm

If you are using maven, I'm happy to point you to the relevant poms. If not, downloading the jars shouldn't be very hard either. (See your first comment for the site from which to fetch them).

Comment: So the snippet above doesn't relate to a logging framework like log4j, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It just logs to text file, none of these loggers log anything database (AFAIK there is no such facility with loggers logging to database unless you code database insert statements with log string as input).